# Using a Named Range for column number look up in VLookup

Tags: excel

I have a worksheet that is 200 columns wide.  I am using VLookup to return values based off of a date in the first column.

Due to the width of the spreadsheet, troubleshooting (or even determining the column number to use) is a real pain. I tried naming the column, and replacing the column 45 with the name, but I get a Value error.

There are two tabs: `recap` and `Roll-up`. In the recap tab, I have:

```
=VLOOKUP(MONTH($C$4),Rollup,45)
```

C4 is the date that users want to look up in the named range Rollup first column.

The Rollup range is defined as:

```
='Roll-up'!$A$2:$FF$15
```

The formula needs to be something non-power Excel users can understand and use for future growth of their workbooks (not that I don't like doing all their work for them).

Comment: is it what you need: `=VLOOKUP(MONTH($C$4),Rollup,Match("Col_Name", A1:Z1,0),0)` where `A1:Z1` is address of header row.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to define the named range `Rollup`? In your question, you also mentioned "a date in the first column." but `$C$4` is not the first column of the worksheet. Did you perhaps refer to the first column in `Rollup`?

Comment: C4 is the date on the recap tab that they want to look up in the named range Rollup first column - which also happens to be the Tab name - sorry for the confusion for where the lookup happens.

Comment: =VLOOKUP(MONTH($C$4),Rollup,MATCH("(EAF) Equivalent availability factor", A2:FF2,0),0) Returns a NA error

Comment: Traced the error, and the column header lookup is happening on the recap tab rather than in the named range Rollup...

Comment: Rollup range: ='Roll-up'!$A$2:$FF$15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I guess you could use something like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(MONTH($C$4),Rollup,MATCH("(EAF) Equivalent availability factor", INDEX(Rollup,1,0),0),0)
```

`MATCH("(EAF) Equivalent availability factor", INDEX(Rollup,1,0),0)` gets the column number in `Rollup` in which there is `(EAF) Equivalent availability factor`.

It's not so simple, and if you want, you should also be able to use a simpler:

```
=VLOOKUP(MONTH($C$4),Rollup,MATCH("(EAF) Equivalent availability factor", 'Roll-up'!$A$2:$FF$2,0),0)
```

To reduce the number of functions, at most. From experience, non-Excel users usually have difficulty with even understanding how `VLOOKUP` works, so I guess if they don't understand it at all, it might be better having something that could be more robust to changes such as row insertions.

---

`INDEX(Rollup,1,0)` by the way gives the first row in the range `Rollup`.

Comment: Your simpler version should work very well for them, all they would need to do is copy and paste into every cell (there are 50 lookups) and fill in the headers. Excellent! Also, thank you for editing my post so that I have a better feel for formatting future questions. But how do you get a "return" in this msg pane...it acts like enter and closes the window.

Comment: @DianM You're welcome! Unfortunately, it's hard to format things in comments (you can bold, italics, link) but that's as far as it gets :(